# Using out to return multiple variables, seems to work but error when trying to output

Tags: c#

I have to write a small program which uses out in c#. Method takes in an int variable and out's 5 other int variables which are modified inside the method with the variable that is taken in.

I seem to have it correctly set up, code is below, but when i try to put the method inside Console.WriteLine () to see if it works I get error.

```
public static void Init (int num, out int param1, out int param2, out int param3, out int param4, out int param5)
        {
            param1 = num * 2;
            param2 = num * 10;
            param3 = num * 100;
            param4 = num * 1000;
            param5 = num * 10000;
        }

int num = 5 ;

Init(num, out int param1, out int param2, out int param3, out int param4, out int param5);
```

Writing the above code seems to work, I say seems since it does not give any errors in Visual Studio and when I run it executes.

Then when I try to put Init inside Console.WriteLine as such:

```
Console.WriteLine(Init(num, out int param1, out int param2, out int param3, out int param4, out int param5));
```

I get Error "Argument 1 cannot convert from void to bool"
I dont seem to have any bool variables at all and Im puzzled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, `Init` returns nothing, so you can't write nothing (`void`) to the console.

`Init` must returns something of type like an int or a bool or a tuple or a class... or you shoud move it out and write what you want to the console if it is what you want.

You can perhaps try this:

```
Init(num, out int param1, out int param2, out int param3, out int param4, out int param5);

Console.WriteLine($"param1={param1}; param2={param2}; param3={param3}; " + 
                  $"param4={param4}; param5={param5}");
```

Here we use `$` for string interpolation where vars between `{}` are substituted to write the values to the console in the string provided.

Answer (score 0):

Oliver's answer should fix the problem for you. You should however avoid using so many `out` variables in a single method call. If you need to return complex data, you should define your own structure or class that holds all those pieces of information and simply return single object of that class from the method.

If you're too lazy to do that, you can also use built-in `Tuple` class that can hold several generic variables. In newer versions of C#, you can also define anonymous types inside the signature of your method. For example:

```
public static (int, int, int, int, int) Init (int num)
{
  return (2, 4, 5, 6, 7);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
var Result = Init(15);
Console.Write($"{Result.Item1}, {Result.Item2}...");
```

Or even better:

```
public static (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int weight) Init(int num)
{
  return (2, 4, 5, 6, 7);
}
```

and call it like:

```
var Result = Init(15);
Console.Write($"{Result.x1}, {Result.y1}...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Console class contain WriteLine() overload method. But Init() method return nothing.For your case,you are giving Init method as first parameter of WriteLine() method.It should return any value(Like string,bool,int).